# pysnmp составить аналог команды snmpwalk

Tags: python, snmp

Не получается при помощи pysnmp составить аналог команды:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c XFiles 172.18.114.6 ifOperStatus
```

Пытаюсь получить таким кодом:

```
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
   getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
      CommunityData(comm),
      UdpTransportTarget(
      (ip, 161), timeout=2.0, retries=0
      ),
      ContextData(),
      ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB','ifOperStatus')))
)
```

Ошибка:

```
pysnmp.smi.error.MibNotFoundError: IF-MIB compilation error(s): missing
```

Но явно копаю не в ту сторону. Вероятно, нужно использовать не `getCmd`?

Answer (score 1):

В этом случае нужно использовать bulkCmd, например так:

```
def GetArrayPortStatus(ip,comm,oid):
 rez=None       
 for errorIndication, errorStatus, \
errorIndex, varBinds in bulkCmd(
    SnmpEngine(),
    CommunityData(comm),
    UdpTransportTarget((ip, 161)),
    ContextData(),
    0, 50,  # GETBULK specific: request up to 50 OIDs in a single response
    ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8')),
    lookupMib=False, lexicographicMode=False):

if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
    break
elif errorStatus:
    print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
            errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex)-1][0] or '?'))
    break
else:
    for varBind in varBinds:
    print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))       
 return rez
```